# How to unsubscribe from my nifty TimerObservable in rxjs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I keep getting the error that unsubscribe is not a function. I'm using rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12.

These are my import statements:

```
import { TimerObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/TimerObservable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
```

This is the TimerObservable in question:

```
countdown = TimerObservable.create(0, 1000).take(6);
```

This kicks off the timer:

```
startCountdownTimer(): void {
    this.countdown.subscribe(
        i => this.timeRemaining = (5 - i).toString(),
        null,
        () => this.toDelete = -1)
}
```

This, well, this doesn't work:

```
cancelCountdownTimer(): void {
    this.countdown.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callers of `subscribe` receive a [subscription](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subscription):

```
startCountdownTimer(): void {
    this.subscription = this.countdown.subscribe(
        i => this.timeRemaining = (5 - i).toString(),
        null,
        () => this.toDelete = -1);
}
```

which has an `unsubscribe` method:

```
cancelCountdownTimer(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: So for every Observable I create, I also need a Subscription. Got it. It seems a little counterintuitive, but that's likely because there are still things I don't understand about RxJs. Thanks!

Comment: You might find this interesting/useful: https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Comment: I did read that when it came out. Always good stuff there! In this particular case, I'm removing modals from an application and replacing them with inline elements, e.g., a new list item appears with a 5-second countdown to deletion and a cancel button. 

Now, something I haven't really considered is whether or not I can replace take(6) with takeUntil(6 or the cancel button is clicked). What do you think?